# Is there any way the input function (Switch) automatically when time frame changes

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create a code with switch button (input or input.bool function) that changes automatically when time frame changed.

Example...
`//@version=5 indicator("input", overlay=true) i_switch = input(true, "On/Off") plot(i_switch ? open : na)` 
in above code the i_switch should only automatically/on enable when the chart timeframe is 5mins if other than 5mins timeframe it should be off.

Could any one please help me on this as I have no experience in pine script.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

`defval` argument is of type [const int](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Type_system.html#const).

> Values of the form const are ones that:
>
> - do not change during script execution
> - are known or can be calculated at compile time

Comment: Bad.... anyway thanks